# Unable to switch among the windows

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am automating using selenium 2.0, my application launches the login page by default in a new window, hence my application has by default two windows. These two windows will remain open always. In this case I could switch between the windows without any problem. The below code is executed without any errors.

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

The problem starts while clicking the menu options a pop up window launches to search the records. Here, I need to switch between these three windows. I tried the below piece of code. It returns only the first two window handles.

Set availableWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();

This popup window is coded in such a way that, "In a .jsp file it is parameterised as window.open()".

Please let me know, if some one could help me on this?

Comment: The below piece of code worked for me, through trial and error. </br> exec.executeScript("return window.focus();");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only seeing 2 window in getWindowHandles(), then the popup is probably a iframe.  In this event, use driver.switchTo().frame() to switch focus to that frame instead of looking for an entirely new window.

Here's the documentation on the switch method:  [http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo%28%29)

Comment: Thanks, The window popus is coded inside the body of the html. There are three iframes to the popup window, hence i tried to switch to these frames to reach my input field. But when i tried to switch to the first frame, an expection throwed "No Such frame" found.

Comment: The below code helped me thanks @PockerDews: JavascriptExecutor exec = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; exec.executeScript("return window.focus();");

Answer (score 0):

One probable solution is to use JavascriptExecutor.executeScript() method to run a javascript code and handle the pop up window without switching into pop up window.

For example, from parent window of pop up window, run a javascript code which is something like this.

```
JavascriptExecutor exec = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;exec.executeScript("var popup = <<popupopener function>>; //operate on popup object to manipulate the markup of pop up window");
```